# Custom styles for IE9 only

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, xml, css

Haven't really seen anyone post about this. I need to call in a style sheet just for IE9 or lower, in my magento 1.9.2 - I'm doing it through xml like so:

```
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/cms.css</name><params/><if>lte IE 9</if></action>
```

But it doesn't seem to show in IE9 or anything lower. I thought my syntax is correct but im not sure.

Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Microsoft has a Knowledge Base article that says “All style tags after
>   the first 30 style tags on an HTML page are not applied in Internet
>   Explorer.” Not only is this KB article wrong (it’s 31, not 30), the
>   full picture is more subtle.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/262161

This problem occurs because the following conditions are true in Internet Explorer:

> All style tags after the first 31 style tags are not applied.
>       All style rules after the first 4,095 rules are not applied.
>       On pages that uses the @import rule to continously import external style sheets that import other style sheets, style sheets that are
>   more than three levels deep are ignored.

If you want to read a little bit more about the problem check out `Alan Storm`: [IE9 fix for Magento.](http://alanstorm.com/ie9_fix_for_magento/)